# multiple select from query Error

Tags: jquery, sql, oracle, oracle11g

I need to write 1 state that would do multiple things.

**Here is first select which selects count and it works fine.**

```
select PLANNED 
  from (SELECT count(FACT.EVENT) AS PLANNED
          FROM FACT FACT 
         WHERE FACT.PLANNEDOTGFLAG = 1 
           AND FACT.STARTDATETIME >= SYSDATE - 365
        )
```

I need to write another statement which would show different information from same table example.

```
select count(effected) 
  from fact 
 where startime between 01/01/2013 and 01/02/2013
```

I was wondering if I can do something like this

```
 select PLANNED, 
        Count_EFFECTED
 from ( SELECT count(FACT.EVENT) AS PLANNED 
          FROM FACT FACT 
         WHERE FACT.PLANNEDOTGFLAG = 1 
           AND FACT.STARTDATETIME >= SYSDATE - 365

        union all

        select count(FACT.effected) AS Count_EFFECTED 
          from fact fact 
         where fact.startime between 01/01/2013 and 01/02/2013
       )
```

---

**3rd Nested Query**

```
SELECT 
     A.PLANNED, 
     B.effec,
     C.XOUND // not working yet.
FROM 
     (SELECT count(FACT.EVENT) AS PLANNED FROM FACT FACT 
      WHERE FACT.PLANNEDOTGFLAG = 1 AND FACT.STARTDATETIME >= SYSDATE - 365)  A,

     (select count(FACT.effected) AS effec from fact fact
      WHERE FACT.STARTDATETIME between 01/01/2013 and 01/02/2013) B
     //how can I add 3rd select which is nested.
     (select round(FACT.ID) AS XOUND
       FROM 
       (SELECT SUM(FACT.CIM)/SUM(FACT.CUST) AS ID
          FROM FACT FACT
          WHERE FACT.STARTDATETIME between 01/01/2013 and 01/02/2013
            AND OTGFLAG = 1 AND PLANNEDOTGFLAG = 0 )) C
```

Comment: I need help with adding 3rd nested query can someone help. please see edit.

Comment: Are you trying get sum of all the 'CIM' columns and sum of all 'CUST' columns  for given where criteria?

Comment: @Renu Yes, getting sum of both and dividing it to get the ratio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second query will give you an error as the table that is resulted in FROM clause will return only one column (2 rows), first row will have `PLANNED_OUTAGES` and 2nd will have `effect` count respectively.

For your requirement you could change your query to:

Included 3rd query:

```
SELECT A.PLANNED_OUTAGES,B.effec, C.ID
  FROM (SELECT count(FACT.EVENT) AS PLANNED 
          FROM FACT FACT 
         WHERE FACT.PLANNEDOTGFLAG = 1 AND FACT.STARTDATETIME >= SYSDATE - 365)  A,
       (select count(FACT.effected) AS effec 
          from fact fact
         WHERE FACT.STARTDATETIME between 01/01/2013 and 01/02/2013) B,
       (SELECT ROUND(SUM(FACT.CIM)/SUM(FACT.CUST)) AS ID
          FROM FACT FACT
         WHERE FACT.STARTDATETIME between 01/01/2013 and 01/02/2013
           AND OTGFLAG = 1 AND PLANNEDOTGFLAG = 0 
         GROUP BY FACT.CIM,FACT.CUST) C
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that worked, I almost had it. something new learned.

Comment: How can I add 3rd Query with is double nested please see edit.

Comment: Are you trying get sum of all the 'CIM' columns and sum of all 'CUST' columns for given where criteria?

Comment: Please see the new query (edited). I haven't tested entire query the but sub query works.let me know if it helps.

Comment: Can you edit out `_OUTAGES` it is suppoed to be only `A.PLANNED`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're getting two different counts from the same table, I suggest using case statements:

```
SELECT 
    Planned_Outages = COUNT(CASE WHEN Fact.PlannedOTGFlag = 1 AND Fact.StartDateTime >= Sysdate - 365 THEN Fact.Event END), 
    Effec = COUNT(CASE WHEN FactStartTime between '01/01/2013' and '01/02/2013' THEN Fact.Effected END)
FROM 
    Fact
```

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite your SQL statement using `CASE` expression:

```
select count(case 
                when plannedotgflag = 1 AND 
                     startdatetime >= SYSDATE - 365
                then 1
             end 
            ) as planned
     , count(case
               when startime between to_date('01/01/2013', 'dd/mm/yyy') and 
                                     to_date('01/02/2013', 'dd/mm/yyy')
               then 1
             end
            ) as effected
  from fact
```